# Adding bundle products via URL query string

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

we have a Magento store (v1.9.2) and I want to be able to add bundle products via a url with the options in the query string.

It is almost working... but the problem is that each bundle option has several items that needs selecting, but the query string will only select one of them.

Example screenshot of the options on the frontend:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/80s1pjl7nfmum8t/Screen%20Shot%202016-04-30%20at%2010.20.02.png?dl=0

Example of the URL:

/checkout/cart/add/product/329/qty/1/?bundle_option[174]=1531&bundle_option[174]=1532&form_key=rGK59KHglVmkjdRg

This should select two items in bundle option 174, but it only selects one.

Can someone please help, I don't know if I am missing something regarding the URL structure, of if the code needs modifying!

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

You are missing some **[]**

So your requested url should be:
http://www.example.org/checkout/cart/add/product/329/qty/1/?bundle_option[174][]=1531&bundle_option[174][]=1532&form_key=rGK59KHglVmkjdRg

---

That is a basic use of array in get parameters.

When you say `bundle_option[174]=1531&bundle_option[174]=1532` you are actually saying that the key `174` of the parameter `bundle_option` is `1531` then you override it right away saying the key `174` of the parameter `bundle_option` is `1532`.

You can try that in any basic php script :
Let's say we call `some.php?bundle_option[174]=1531&bundle_option[174]=1532` containing this code

```
<?php var_dump($_GET);
```

It will echo :

```
some.php:1:
array (size=1)
  'bundle_option' => 
    array (size=1)
      174 => string '1532' (length=4)
```

When what you need, and what Magento expect you to have for checkbox options in which you can have multiple choice checked, is an array of array.

So with the exact same file as above:
If we call `some.php?bundle_option[174][]=1531&bundle_option[174][]=1532`, that will give you an array of array:

```
some.php:1:
array (size=1)
  'bundle_option' => 
    array (size=1)
      174 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string '1531' (length=4)
          1 => string '1532' (length=4)
```

If you actually have a Magento controller to test with, you can also use an action there and look the result of the query parameters using

```
Zend_Debug::dump( $this->getRequest()->getParams() );
```