# Magento 1.9 / OpenMage: Built In Mechanismm To Pre-select Bundle or Configurable Product Options

Tags: magento-1.9

After reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36953069/adding-bundle-products-via-url-query-string) which appears to be discussing adding configured bundle products to the cart (using URL params), I remembered one of my clients asking me recently if it was possible for their sales associates to send clients a link (via email for example) to a bundle product that's preconfigured.

The use case is that a client could be on the phone asking about a specific bundle or configurable product. When the sales associate sends a link, they then have to confusingly explain to the client that they need to select some options.

What would be better is if the sales associate could send a link with preconfigured bundle (and or configurable) options preselected using URL parameters.

I'm a developer and so I'm happy to write something. But has anything like this been done before? Perhaps an old 1/2 finished extension or any pointers to save some time?

Comment: Not  exactly what you want, but if the customer has an account, the backend users can add product to the customer's cart, see https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31183/add-update-customers-cart-from-admin

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add product to cart via url but you would have to create your own module with controller that based on url paramaters saves products and redirects to cart.

I did something like that for [Magento 1 for simple and configurable product](https://www.degriz.eu/add-product-to-cart-with-url-83) and for [Magento 2 for simple](https://www.degriz.eu/add-product-to-cart-with-url). But it does not support bundle products atm but i think it could be done. But I think for regular user there should be some url generator for this asn url would probably be complex.
Example:
[https://www.example.com/quickcart/addtocart/add/?sku=bundle_product_sku&qty=1&option[option_id_1]=value_id_1&option[option_id_2]=value_id_2&coupon=coupon_code](https://www.example.com/quickcart/addtocart/add/?sku=bundle_product_sku&qty=1&option%5Boption_id_1%5D=value_id_1&option%5Boption_id_2%5D=value_id_2&coupon=coupon_code)

and than adding those paramaters before saving product something like:

```
        // Check if the product is a bundle product
        if ($product->getTypeId() == 'bundle') {
            // Add bundle options
            $options = $this->getRequest()->getParam('options', []);
            $params['bundle_option'] = $options;
            
            // Handle bundle selections
            $bundleOptions = $this->getRequest()->getParam('bundle_option');
            if (is_array($bundleOptions)) {
                foreach ($bundleOptions as $optionId => $selectionIds) {
                    $params['bundle_option'][$optionId] = $selectionIds;
                }
            }
        }
        $this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);
```